# Any BI or log tools to import dumb file

Tags: text-processing, logs

Currently we do not have any log tools for filtering a huge dumb file. Is there any open source BI or log tool able to import a dumb file and do auto/selectable filtering?

Current dumb file example:

```
2019-02-11 03:06:30.202  INFO maskParams=false
2019-02-11 03:06:30.205  INFO Start request :: ipAddress=103.22.200.95
2019-02-11 03:06:30.205  INFO  User-Agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.1; zh-cn; MI MAX 2 Build/NMF26F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/61.0.3163.128 Mobile 
Safari/537.36 XiaoMi/MiuiBrowser/10.5.1
2019-02-11 03:06:30.205  INFO  Request Query String=[customer_name]
2019-02-11 03:06:30.335  INFO  Checking current ip address
2019-02-11 03:06:30.335  ERROR Not a valid ip address 2408:84e4:412:4b02:73cd:9684:1ab0:8437
2019-02-11 03:06:30.336  INFO  Get country from GeoIpRange, ip =2408:84e4:412:4b02:73cd:9684:1ab0:8437
2019-02-11 03:06:30.336  ERROR Not a valid ip address 2408:84e4:412:4b02:73cd:9684:1ab0:8437
2019-02-11 03:06:30.385  INFO  End request (00:00:00.183)
```

After importing the dumb file, able to provide me the below details:

- Start Date and time/
- End Date and time/
- customer name/
- no valid ip address details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many open source log collectors and indexers:

Splunk? Elasticsearch? Logstash? Kibana?

Are they BI tools? I'm not sure. Only if you plot some business metrics I guess.

Comment: i had tested Splunk and it really give me what I wanted.

Thanks!